# Is there any bridge beetwen Tor and Freenet? Is there way to bridge Freenet site like a Tor hidden service?

Tags: onion-services, bridge, onion-routing

Is there any ***bridge*** beetwen **Tor** and **[Freenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenet)**?

Is there a way to bridge Freenet site like a Tor hidden service ( onion domain )?

E.g. setting up site in Freenet network means, that this site splitted like a slices of garlic among many unknown users of Freenet.

Setting up hidden service in Tor network, means that it will be reached with onion's multi-layer encryption routing, **only**. There is ***point of failure*** similar to ordinary Internet - ***one physical server***.

Is there way to setting up Freenet's hidden site, that will be reached via .onion domain from Tor network?

To obtain at once [**garlic's** fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freenet#Distributed_storage_and_caching_of_data) and [**onion's** routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_routing).

Comment: Your question is hard to understand for people who only know Tor but are not familiar with Freenet.  Maybe you could add a couple links to relevant documents that explain the concepts you refer to?

Comment: Ok, I improve it.

Comment: Check: [What are the best TOR2Web anonymous gateways?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/what-are-the-best-tor2web-anonymous-gateways).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at http://2vlqpcqpjlhmd5r2.onion.lu/ it is a web-bridge to .onion sites, that bridges to a Freenet to Tor bridge.

EDIT: Here’s a currently working bridge, pointing to a site hosted in Freenet: https://freenet7cul5qsz6.onion.cab/freenet:USK@s9sxY2cTJWHKRsTuBTkjrXW4HfzrdUlwFqft1mzV0Gs,2E4DOMYy-~zOdp8-5OQH2IcmLfey0AOIkms-73Mx2tI,AQACAAE/freenet-funding/42/#sec-6

Comment: Not any more. `Host 2vlqpcqpjlhmd5r2.onion.lu not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
`

Comment: @clacke upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy I think. Let's say that you have a Freenet node installed, and are connected to some network (Strangers or Friends). The URL for accessing your node is `http://127.0.0.1:8888`. If you were running Tor on the same machine, you would just set up a hidden service in your torrc file with that as the HiddenServicePort. But running both Freenet and Tor on the same machine is unwise. Better is running both on VMs.

See https://freenetproject.org/documentation.html for more about Freenet.

Comment: It would be great to see big cross bridge for all of dark networks, freenet, i2p, HS of Tor, etc...

Comment: I don't know about a big cross bridge, but there are already small ones, or so I've heard. And then there's [GammaDX](http://anarplex.net/services/gammadx.html).

Comment: That GammaDX link tells me that it exists, but is not very informative of where it exists. :-)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The two addresses below now both redirect to http://sigaintevyh2rzvw.onion/, so it seems they closed their node. I'm not aware of any other public Freenet node on TOR.

---

Yes. There is a public Freenet node on TOR, or maybe there are two.

- http://freenet7cul5qsz6.onion/
- http://freenovfka2ploir.onion/

They are both set up identically, even with the same information on an about page ([freenet7...](http://freenet7cul5qsz6.onion.link/constant/about.html), [freenov...](http://freenovfka2ploir.onion.link/constant/about.html)), so I don't know if they are the same machine with two addresses or if one is a mirror of the other. `freenet7...` seems to be the official one, but maybe they put up the other address because the original is [blocked in the ahmia.fi index](https://ahmia.fi/address/freenet7cul5qsz6.onion), probably due to the unaccepted, now filtered, content mentioned in the about page.

It's run by the SIGAINT people, who [bought it from the previous admin earlier this year](https://www.reddit.com/r/onions/comments/34fdz0/sigaint_freenet_proxy/). (announcement on /r/onions, see also the about page mentioned earlier)

Anyway, this in combination with e.g. http://onion.link/ means that Freenet is now [indexed by Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Afreenet7cul5qsz6.onion.link) (about 5000 results).

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, I know, but I have worked out how to run a Freenet node through OnionCat, or with a clearnet proxy linked via OnionCat.

https://dbshmc5frbchaum2.onion/Freenet-OnionCat.html