# What are the best Tor2Web anonymous gateways?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, web-proxy

What are the best Tor2Web anonymous gateways to make Hidden Web-Services available on clearnet/standard Internet?

Comment: Although, every one of these sites would be a nice middle-man proxy, giving the Grey Man - [who owns it of course](http://walls4joy.com/walls/people/g-man-gman-half-life-4309-3255x2183.jpg), all your details. I don't understand why anyone *concerned with privacy and deniability* would trust a single chokepoint node.

Comment: They are not always working properly, and sometimes, you cannot access what you need. At times, they bring ordinary web sites and claim that they are onion sites. They are occasionally problematic.

Comment: Are there also Gateways that allow to connect via plain http?
All Gateways listed here only allow https! (Which is better ofc, but leads to certificate issues)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are few available Tor2web network gateways:

- *.tor2web.org,
- *.tor2web.fi (managed by [Ahmia - Onion Search Engine](https://ahmia.fi/search/)),
- *.tor2web.blutmagie.de (managed by O.Selke with no block),
- *.onion.sh (managed by my unknown friend: “hey anon!”).

Source: [Tor2web: exposing the darknet on Internet (PDF)](http://e-privacy.winstonsmith.org/2013/atti/16_ep2013_pellerano_tor2web.pdf)

**How it works**

Whenever you see a URL like http://xxx.onion/, that's a Tor hidden Web service. Just replace .onion with .tor2web.org to use the Tor2web proxy network.

Example: https://duskgytldkxiuqc6.tor2web.org/

Answer (score 9):

Some people like http://onion.direct .

However I am a fan of [onion.link](http://onion.link).

I do know at least in terms of size of GOOG index, the results come out to:

- onion.direct | 21k
- onion.cab    | 232k
- onion.link   | 1060k

Both onion.link as well as onion.cab do caching.  AFAIK the other various t2w gateways do not.

Comment: Maybe you should disclose why you are a fan of onion.city: https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2015-February/036865.html :-)

Comment: I'm a fan of onion.city only because onion.city is awesome!

Comment: https://onion.direct/ still exists, but has stopped its service.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tor-gateways.de` where you can use one of the following syntaxes:

```
https://.s1.tor-gateways.de/
https://*.s1.tor-gateways.de
https://.s2.tor-gateways.de/
https://*.s2.tor-gateways.de
https://.s3.tor-gateways.de/
https://*.s3.tor-gateways.de
https://.s4.tor-gateways.de/
https://*.s4.tor-gateways.de
https://.s5.tor-gateways.de/
https://*.s5.tor-gateways.de
```

Comment: The domain tor-gateways.de seems to be for sale.