# Access tor sites without installing a tor browser, but via a PHP url?

Tags: vpn, browsers

Can one setup some type of PHP service that routes url info to a PHP script that outputs tor websites without having to install a tor browser on our client machine?

Comment: I don't know about PHP specifically, buy you're probably looking for something like: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/what-are-the-best-tor2web-anonymous-gateways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use torsocks. It comes with pretty much ever major Linux distribution. Torsocks will automatically push the request through the Tor network.

start the tor daemon.

torsocks myapp.php mywebsitse.onion